# What kind of format is this date?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

What kind of format is
  *2012-05-02T15:44:20.000Z*

I've been trying to get it to parse, but having some issues with this section.

```
NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"published"];
        NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
        NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        NSString *dateofarticle = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:articleDate];
```

It is not RFC822.  That's about all I know.

Comment: Post your code so we can help.

Comment: Since you have a fixed format date/time, you can't use the standard date and time styles. You need to provide an explicit date format. There must be dozens of existing questions covering this.

Comment: Check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876954/whats-the-most-simplest-way-to-parse-rfc3339-date-string-in-ios

Comment: its an ISO 8601 datetime format, refer same post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201216/is-there-a-simple-way-of-converting-an-iso8601-timestamp-to-a-formatted-nsdate

Comment: Someone had answered correctly as I see the answer in my Inbox, but it is no longer here for me to accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"published"];
NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'"];
NSString *dateofarticle = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:articleDate];
```